# Cómo puedo mantener el tamaño de la página web igual al tamaño de la pantalla del teléfono?

Tags: html, css

hice una página web y tengo un problema. Ocurre que cuando alejo la pantalla (-zoom) del teléfono, mi página WEB se sigue achicando hasta cierto punto... Cómo puedo mantener el tamaño de la página igual al tamaño de la pantalla?

Dejo unas imágenes para que se hagan una idea

Así se ve cuando alejo la pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así quiero que se vea aunque intente alejar la pantalla, es decir, que mantenga su tamaño aunque intente achicar la página web.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba usando estos meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, bootstrap, mobile, app, landing, ios, android, responsive">
```

Y probe el tuyo solo y tampoco me daba solución

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Estaba pensando que estoy usando un div que se desplaza con la pantalla cuando bajo o subo... podría ser ese el problema?

Comment: Si se desplaza hacia la izquierda es porque probablemente estés trabajando *"offscreen"*, fíjate si son necesarios los divs con el atributo `left` que sobrepasen el tamaño de la pantalla, de ser necesario cambialos a porcentaje

Comment: No sé si ya solucionaste el problema, acabo de revisar tu página web y no veo ningún movimiento a menos que haga zoom. Hice pruebas usando `user-scalable=no` y la página se ve bien.

Comment: Tienes razón, funciona bien... Lo probé en un teléfono android y no hay problemas, pero en un iphone hay un div que sobresale y genera ese problema.

Comment: Debe ser problema del tamaño del Iphone, lo acabo de probar en otro Iphone más moderno y no hay problema... Disculpa por hacerte perder tiempo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Añade en tu cabecera la siguiente línea:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Encuentre más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Sigue igual :/, el problema es que se desplaza hacia la izquierda y no regresa al estado normal...

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade los metadatos que estás usando en tu head. Estás usando únicamente el meta `viewport` que te pasé ?

Comment: Sí, lo probe solo y no me funciono... Arriba puse los que estaba usando antes del que tu me pasaste.

Comment: Cabe aclarar, aunque tal ves ya lo sepas, que si estás probando el sitio en un navegador (sea móvil o no), debes siempre limpiar la caché por completo

Comment: La verdad es que soy nuevo en programación, lo que ocurre es que la página al desplazarla hacia la derecha se mueve y se pierde la visión completa de la página web hasta que vuelvo a desplazarla a la derecha... No sé cómo evitar que se desplace hacia la izquierda cuando uso el dedo...

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que tienes un div fuera del viewport inicial. Añade algo más de código, lo que creas que sea necesario

Comment: Cómo puedo saber cuáles div están en el viewport inicial?

Comment: Debes revisar tu css, atributos como `left` con posiciones en `absolute` te pueden generar el problema, si es necesario también puedes revisar la propiedad `overflow`. Mira este ejemplo, juega con él y a lo mejor te aclara dudas: https://codepen.io/davidjb/pen/ENGqpv

Comment: Moviendo algunas cosas me acabo de dar cuenta que el body de mi web no alcanza a cubrir la pantalla completa del teléfono... Algo de ésto puede afectar? <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="30">

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85763/discussion-between-jheyman-mejia-and-matias-nicolas-nunez-rivas).